# How to avoid reinstalling Ubuntu every time a GPU driver fails?

Tags: drivers, radeon, amdgpu-pro

I have a Sapphire Radeon R7 240 with 4 GB of VRAM that is not being correctly recognized at install, so I download the AMDGPU-PRO tar and install the package, but it fails and after rebooting the screen is garbled.

I tried to use <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> but there seems to be no way to start the system with a terminal so I can unistall and try again with another driver.

The same procedure I am following worked fine in a virtual machine running over Windows 7, but when installed Ubuntu to the bare metal it does not work.

Any hints, suggestions, or solutions will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After playing with Ubuntu for a week, I found that 17.40 does not support my hardware and have returned to Windows. I'll wait another decade to test this out :(

Answer (score 1):

You want to switch the `tty` in older Ubuntus you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> up to <kbd>F6</kbd> to get to the first `tty1` and your GUI would normally be on `tty7` which you could call with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Since 17.10 however this has changed and you have your login screen on `tty1` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), your GUI on `tty2` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) and the rest up to `tty7` are unused and created on the fly if you should call them. So use here <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to get a `tty`.

All you need to do there is logging in by supplying your username and password, there you go and can change even if the GUI output fails.

Another way is to hold down <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> while the machine is booting up, this would lead you into the grub menu, where you can choose `Advanced Options → Kernel x.xx.x-xx-generic (recovery)` which will lead you to the recovery menu.

There you simply choose enable network, which in return starts up network capability and remounts your drive in `read/write` mode, and then drop to a root shell, where you can apply your fix.